# Should PreferenceCategories have keys?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have an Android app, in which I use [`Preference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)s. They are grouped with [`PreferenceCategory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceCategory.html)'s.

My `PreferenceCategory`'s have keys (`android:key="setting"`), like the ones in the [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Groups) for settings (which I used myself to learn & make mine).

**But is this a recommended way of doing preferences, a convention, or does is just happen to be that way in the tutorial?** I don't have to refer to most of the categories in my code, just the preferences inside, so I see no real reason to have keys with all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is this a recommended way of doing preferences, a convention, or does is just happen to be that way in the tutorial?

No, you don't need to set keys for your `PreferenceCategories`, if you're not doing anything with them.

You can add `Preferences` to your `PreferenceCategory` by accessing it with `findPreference(your_preference_category_key)` and then calling `addPreference(...)` on it. But since you're not doing that you don't need to set any key for it.

Comment: Can you find any source for that? I don't require it, but it would just make an answer look a little more convincing. ;)